# Number of Inhabited planets (N bit protocol)

Tags: combinatorics

God is fed up with the universe and wants to destroy it. After several pleadings, God agrees to defer his decision but only if each inhabited planet identifies with certainty how many planets (N > 1) are inhabited in total. Each inhabited planet assigns a mathematician. You are from earth and you are declared the leader.

God explains to you that every night, each mathematician (including you) will write down a bit (0 or 1). God will then collect the bits, look at them, and redistribute them to the mathematicians according to some CYCLIC PERMUTATION, which could be different every night.

Before the bit-passing begins, you have the opportunity to broadcast to your fellow mathematicians your instructions through GOD. Can you design a protocol that will succeed no matter what the GOD does?

You have no way to communicate to other planets, other than through GOD as per above rules.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPermutation.html and the shift k ≠ 0, N.

I couldn't progress much to set-up a plan & solve this.

Comment: This is more like a question from programming, but you showed no efforts anyway. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Looks like someone has taken a 10 year old puzzle and repackaged it. I think this originated on [xkcd wiki puzzles section](http://web.archive.org/web/20160122051934/wiki.xkcd.com/irc/puzzles#Yet_more_prisoners), now only accessible in the wayback machine. I would be very interested to hear where you heard this version from, and if so would be happy to share the solution.

Comment: I heard about this problem from one of my senior friend who works in IT/Software.  Say, Earth's leader would send a 1 on the first night & all other 0's. Whoever receives that 1 on the first night would send 1's on every multiples of 1 nights. Now the person who receives the 1 on the 2nd night would send 1's only on multiple of 2 nights. But I am not able to find a way such that all the planet leaders determine N, the total number of inhabited planets. Could you please help me a bit? Any pointer would do really great? Thanks a lot in anticipation. High Regards, Shamik Banerjee

Comment: See https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16168/the-circular-prison-of-unknown-size

Comment: Thanks a lot. High Regards ...